# Finding the maximum sublist in Prolog

Tags: prolog, kadanes-algorithm

I'm new to Prolog and trying to solve instances of the [maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

I have got the following quite elegant C++ code:

```
int maxSubArray(vector<int> List)
{
    int maxsofar = 0;
    int maxendinghere = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++)
    {
        maxendinghere = max(maxendinghere+List[i], 0);
        maxsofar = max(maxsofar, maxendinghere);
    }
    return maxsofar;
}
```

And here is my Prolog code:

```
max(X,X,X).
max(X,Y,X) :- X>Y.
max(X,Y,Y) :- X<Y. %define max function

prev(L,T,H) :-
   reverse(L,[H|T1]),
   reverse(T,T1).  %split L to H(last element) and T(the remaining list)

f([],0,0).
f(L,M,N) :-
   f(L1,M1,N1),
   prev(L,L1,E),
   max(M1,N,M),
   max(K,0,N), 
   K is N1+E.
```

I try to get the maximum sum from `f(L,M,N)`, where `L` is the list, `M` is the result (maximum sum, also like the variable "maxsofar" in C++ code) I want to get, `N` is a intermediary variable as the "maxendinghere" in C++ code. I want to get answer of `L` from its former list `L1`, and the relation of variables are just the same as the C++ code.

However, the following query does not work:

```
?- f([1,2,3],X,Y).
is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Your query to `f(L1, M1, N1)` happens with `L1` uninstantiated. It looks like a logic error or typo perhaps. This ultimately leads to `K is N1+E` being executed with one or both of `N1` and `E` not having a value, which yields the error you saw. On a different note, you can define `prev` nicely with `append`: `prev(L, T, H) :- append(T, [H], L).`

Comment: Hi, with the function of `prev(L,L1,E)`, `L1` and `E` can be inferred. I'm still confused.

Comment: Oh, I get it. It's the matter of the order!

Comment: Yes, Prolog runs the queries in a clause in order, and according to operator precedence.

Comment: I understand that 'elegance' is subjective, but why on earth your C++ code ignores List[0] ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! It's been edited.

Comment: After resolving the issue of proper order of subgoals in your predicate, is your problem now solved? It's unclear.

Comment: I think so, but what is unclear?

Answer (score 3):

This answer shows a Prolog port of [kadanes-algorithm](/questions/tagged/kadanes-algorithm) 
based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We define `zs_maxmum/2` like so:

```
zs_maxmum(Zs, MSF) :-
   zs_maxmum_(Zs, 0,_, 0,MSF).

zs_maxmum_([], _,_, MSF,MSF).
zs_maxmum_([Z|Zs], MEH0,MEH, MSF0,MSF) :-
   max(0,MEH0+Z)  #= MEH1,
   max(MSF0,MEH1) #= MSF1,
   zs_maxmum_(Zs, MEH1,MEH, MSF1,MSF).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- zs_maxmum([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4], Max).
Max = 6.

?- zs_maxmum([-2,3,4,-5,8,-12,100,-101,7], Max).
Max = 100.
```

A few remarks:

- We don't actually operate on arrays, but on *lists*.
- We admit arbitrary sublists, including `[]`. The goal `zs_maxmum([-2,-3,-4], 0)` succeeds.

Comment: The could profit from generalizing it to arbitrary values, not necessarily starting at 0.