# Maximum Subarray (Kadane's algorithm) - Tail recursion

Tags: prolog, tail-recursion, kadanes-algorithm

i am trying to implement [Kadane's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) in Prolog.
One of the requirements is a tail call (recursion).

I have tried many possibilities but without success. 
Here is my code:

```
max_sum(L, S) :-
    S is 0,
    H is 0,
    max_sum(L, H, S).

max_sum([], S, S).
max_sum([X | L], H, S) :-
    (   H + X < 0 -> NewH is 0; NewH is H + X),
    (   S < H + X -> NewS is NewH; NewS is S),
    length(L, N),
    (   N < 1 -> max_sum(L, NewS, NewS); max_sum(L, NewH, NewS)).
```

NewH, NewS are temp values (we cant assign a value twice in Prolog right?).
Can i ask for a hint?

Edit:

```
[trace]  ?- max_sum([1, 2, 3], S).
   Call: (7) max_sum([1, 2, 3], _G8907) ? creep
   Call: (8) _G8907 is 0 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 0 is 0 ? creep
   Call: (8) _G8991 is 0 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 0 is 0 ? creep
   Call: (8) max_sum([1, 2, 3], 0, 0) ? creep
   Call: (9) 0+1<0 ? creep
   Fail: (9) 0+1<0 ? creep
   Redo: (8) max_sum([1, 2, 3], 0, 0) ? creep
   Call: (9) _G8994 is 0+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 1 is 0+1 ? creep
   Call: (9) 0<0+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 0<0+1 ? creep
   Call: (9) _G8997 is 1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 1 is 1 ? creep
   Call: (9) length([2, 3], _G8998) ? creep
   Exit: (9) length([2, 3], 2) ? creep
   Call: (9) 2<1 ? creep
   Fail: (9) 2<1 ? creep
   Redo: (8) max_sum([1, 2, 3], 0, 0) ? creep
   Call: (9) max_sum([2, 3], 1, 1) ? creep
   Call: (10) 1+2<0 ? creep
   Fail: (10) 1+2<0 ? creep
   Redo: (9) max_sum([2, 3], 1, 1) ? creep
   Call: (10) _G9000 is 1+2 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 3 is 1+2 ? creep
   Call: (10) 1<1+2 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 1<1+2 ? creep
   Call: (10) _G9003 is 3 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 3 is 3 ? creep
   Call: (10) length([3], _G9004) ? creep
   Exit: (10) length([3], 1) ? creep
   Call: (10) 1<1 ? creep
   Fail: (10) 1<1 ? creep
   Redo: (9) max_sum([2, 3], 1, 1) ? creep
   Call: (10) max_sum([3], 3, 3) ? creep
   Call: (11) 3+3<0 ? creep
   Fail: (11) 3+3<0 ? creep
   Redo: (10) max_sum([3], 3, 3) ? creep
   Call: (11) _G9006 is 3+3 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 6 is 3+3 ? creep
   Call: (11) 3<3+3 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 3<3+3 ? creep
   Call: (11) _G9009 is 6 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 6 is 6 ? creep
   Call: (11) length([], _G9010) ? creep
   Exit: (11) length([], 0) ? creep
   Call: (11) 0<1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 0<1 ? creep
   Call: (11) max_sum([], 6, 6) ? creep
   Exit: (11) max_sum([], 6, 6) ? creep
   Exit: (10) max_sum([3], 3, 3) ? creep
   Exit: (9) max_sum([2, 3], 1, 1) ? creep
   Exit: (8) max_sum([1, 2, 3], 0, 0) ? creep
   Exit: (7) max_sum([1, 2, 3], 0) ? creep
```

In Call(11) i have a good result (6) from this simple example. How can I end the function at this point without returning? It is my problem.

Result from this code is S = 0, not S = 6.

Final edit (working code):

```
max_sum(L, S) :-
    max_sum(L, 0, 0, S).

max_sum([], _, S, S).
max_sum([X | L], H, F, S) :-
    NewH is max(0, H + X),
    (F < H + X -> NewF is NewH; NewF is F),
    max_sum(L, NewH, NewF, S).
```

Where:

- S - final result,
- F - maximum_so_far,
- H - maximum_ending_here,
- X - head of list,
- L - list,
- NewH, NewF - temp values.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? When you say *without success*, what does that mean? And, correct, you cannot *re-assign* (more properly stated, *reinstantiate*) a variable within a predicate clause without backtracking.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the question is edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a slightly altered version of the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32111783/6101159) proposed by @repeat:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

zs_max([Z|Zs], MSF) :-
   zs_max_(Zs, Z, Z, MSF).

zs_max_([], _, MSF, MSF).
zs_max_([Z|Zs], MEH0, MSF0, MSF) :-
   max(Z, MEH0+Z)  #= MEH1,
   max(MSF0, MEH1) #= MSF1,
   zs_max_(Zs, MEH1, MSF1, MSF).
```

First, the sample queries from the original [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32111783/6101159) that yield the same results:

```
   ?- zs_max([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4], Max).
Max = 6
   ?- zs_max([-2,3,4,-5,8,-12,100,-101,7], Max).
Max = 100
```

However this version is more general, in that it works with arbitrary values (as suggested by @false in the comment to [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32111783/6101159)). This is accomplished by starting with the value of the first element of the list instead of 0. Thus the following query yields a different result:

```
   ?- zs_max([-2,-3,-4], X).
X = -2
   ?- zs_maxmum([-2,-3,-4], X).
X = 0
```

Another difference is that the empty list has no solution:

```
   ?- zs_max([], X).
no
   ?- zs_maxmum([], X).
X = 0
```

I think this behaviour is more reasonable, as the empty list has no sublist and hence no sums of sublists from which to choose a maximum. However, if desired, a special case for the empty list can be easily added:

```
zs_max([], replaceThisWithAReasonableValue).
```

Answer (score 3):

1. This question is, in fact, a duplicate of 
   "[Finding the maximum sublist in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27675467/4609915)".
2. There is a bounty is offered for it, so it cannot be flagged as a duplicate.
3. I propose using my [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32111783/4609915)—it is based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) and runs with SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Note to self is still valid.

Comment: A HO-free version may help. Otherwise there is too much at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

the standard way is to add an output parameter, that gets unified when the recursion stops. Something like

```
max_sum(L, S) :-
    max_sum(L, 0, 0, S).

max_sum([], _, S, S).
...
```

Then, your code is way more complex than needed: both versions listed on Wikipedia don't require any test, or length/2 computation.
Try to simplify it leaving just the computation (you can use for instance `Max_ending_here is max(0, H + X),` and the tail recursive call.